# How to fix "syntax error on token abstract" error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, abstract

Given the following code :

```
package core;

public abstract class GeometricElement {

    private float area; 
    public abstract void calculateArea( ); //will be implemented in subclasses 

    public float getArea( ) 
    { 
        this.calculateArea( ); 
        return area; 
    } 

}


package core;

public class abstract PerfectPolygon extends GeometricElement 
{

    public abstract void calculateArea( );


    private float length;
    private int sides;

     public float getRadius()  {    return this.length; }
     public float getSides()  { return this.sides; }

     public void setRadius(float newLength) {this.length = newLength;}
     public void setSides(float newSides) {this.length = newSides;}



}



package core;

public class PerfectTriangle extends PerfectPolygon {

    PerfectTriangle() {}
    public void calculateArea( ) { }


}



package core;

public class Square extends PerfectPolygon {

    Square() {}
    public void calculateArea( ) {}

}
```

package core;

```
public class Circle extends GeometricElement 
{
    private float radius;



    Circle() {}

    public float getRadius()  { return this.radius; }
    public void setRadius(float newRadius)  {this.radius = newRadius;}
    public void calculateArea( ) {}

}
```

I'm at the beginning of my project ,however , I cannot seem to go ahead since the Eclipse throws an error of : 
1) "Syntax error on token "abstract", delete this token" in class PerfectPolygon
2) " PerfectPolygon cannot be resolved to a type" in class Square
3) "PerfectPolygon cannot be resolved to a type" in class PerfectTriangle

Please notice that I wrote almost no code , I've just starting writing the code , but
from some reason the Eclipse won't allow this little peace of code to compile .
Any idea why ? 
I'd appreciate your help

Regards,
Ron

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
abstract class
```

instead of

```
class abstract
```

Answer (score 3):

The class should read:

```
public abstract class PerfectPolygon extends GeometricElement { ...
```

Just like your other abstract class, that compiles.